# Coding a basic multi-threaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to create 2 threads, one does the max and one gives the average of a list of numbers entered in the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

void * thread1(int length, int array[] )
{

int ii = 0;
int smallest_value = INT_MAX;
        for (; ii < length; ++ii)
        {
                if (array[ii] < smallest_value)
                {
                        smallest_value = array[ii];
                }
        }
 printf("smallest is: %d\n", smallest_value);


}

void * thread2()
{

  printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
  int average;
  int min;
  int max;

  int how_many;
  int i;
  int status;
  pthread_t tid1,tid2;

  printf("How many numbers?: ");
  scanf("%d",&how_many);
  int ar[how_many];
  printf("Enter the list of numbers: ");
  for (i=0;i<how_many;i++){
  scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
  }

//for(i=0;i<how_many;i++)
//printf("%d\n",ar[i]);

        pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1(how_many,ar),NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
        return 0;
  exit(0);
}
```

I just made the first thread, which is to print out the min. number, but I have the following errors when compiling:

```
How many numbers?: 3
Enter the list of numbers: 1
2
3
Smallest: 1
Segmentation fault
```

How should I go on and fix the seg. fault?

Comment: `array` is an `int`.  You probably mean to declare the function with `int *array` instead of `int array`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am now down to `.c:58: error: expected expression before int
.c:58: error: too few arguments to function thread1
`

Comment: void *thread1() seems to return a value..

Comment: I changed line 57 to `pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1( how_many, *ar),NULL);`
Now it compiles but I get a segmentation fault :\

Comment: ``pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1(how_many,ar),NULL);`` here you're calling the function ``thread1``, rather then sending the function pointer to ``pthread_create``. You need to do it like this ``pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1, args);``. I think you're allowed just one argument so you may use a structure to contain both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments like you're trying to in pthread_create.

Create a structure like:

```
struct args_t
{
  int length;
  int * array;
};
```

then initialize a structure with your array and length.

```
args_t *a = (args_t*)malloc(sizeof(args_t));
//initialize the array directly from your inputs
```

Then do

```
pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1,(void*)a);
```

Then just cast the argument back to an args_t.

Hope that helps.